# Populating values from two or more fields into one field using field calculator in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have state-county-specific data. In my attribute table, I have a unique county number for each county in the state. The problem is each of them is in separate fields like there's a field that only has the IL county numbers & it's null wherever the other fields have the other state's county number as it is shown in the figure:

[image]

What I want to do is combine them all so it can be in a single field for example I want to create a single field that has all the county numbers from each state.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You could certainly use Calculate Field to assign a new column to the first not-NULL value, but the results might not be unique. Please [Edit] the Question to specify what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The following field calculate will create a single value.  The assumption behind my code is that in any one row of data you always have 1 ID number and 3 `Null` entries.

You need to have created a numeric field and you run the following field calculate on it. In my example I calculate into a field I called `combi`.

[image: Field calculation]

For your convenience here is the Code block:

```py
def test(x):
    if x is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
def NotNull(lstValues):
    v = list(filter(test, lstValues))
    return v[0]
```

You obviously need to put in YOUR field names in the expression, I had to spoof up some names to test the code.

```
NotNull([!IL!,!OH!,!MI!])
```